# How does while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) work?

Tags: php, mysqli

On about the 40th line of the PHP doc below where the `WHILE` statement is, instead of giving a conditional statement to evaluate, it seems to declare a new variable `$row` instead and set it equal to something? Wouldn't this always evaluate to true? What is the purpose of it? Why do the WHILE statement at all?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
table {
    width: 100%;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

table, td, th {
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 5px;
}

th {text-align: left;}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<?php
$q = intval($_GET['q']);

$con = mysqli_connect('localhost','peter','abc123','my_db');
if (!$con) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}

mysqli_select_db($con,"ajax_demo");
$sql="SELECT * FROM user WHERE id = '".$q."'";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

echo "<table>
<tr>
<th>Firstname</th>
<th>Lastname</th>
<th>Age</th>
<th>Hometown</th>
<th>Job</th>
</tr>";
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['FirstName'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['LastName'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['Age'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['Hometown'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['Job'] . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
mysqli_close($con);
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Protip: not a very good and attracting title. Nor, do we fix someone else's tutorials.

Comment: plus, your db selection; that's going to fail somehow.

Comment: ?? I wasn't asking anyone to 'fix' anything.  I was simply trying to understand a concept of an authors code.  Is that not a valid question for this site?(this is my first ever posted question). if so I'll take my questions elsewhere.

Comment: If you've read [how to ask questions on StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) you would know that a question like this is not suited for SO.

Comment: i've read them already. A) It seems to fit in the recommended topics (on topic)  B)It was not vague. I provided background and asked specific questions (be specific).  C) looked up questions and a simular question has not been asked(do research). can You help me understand what was specifically wrong with the question?

Comment: That's what I thought. We're you having a bad day?

Comment: I get why the OP asked this question if all the documentation says "while evaluates an expression," but this behavior is definitely different

Answer (score 7):

`mysqli_fetch_array()` fetches a single result row for you. When you call it the first time, it returns the first one. When you call it the second time, it returns the second one - and so on. So by doing a `while` loop on it, you keep getting results until there are no more results. By setting `$row` to it, you make sure the same variable gets the results every time.